# How can I redirect to another webpage from my embedded video on HTML?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am coding an HTML Website and I embedded the video successfully.

```
<section class="section1" id="videopage">
    <video width=100%, playsinline autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="Intro_BLACK.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
</section>
```

This worked very well. I want to know, however, how can I link a website on this embedded video. If I click the video, I want to redirect to another webpage. I tried the below code, but it didn't work. Thanks in advance.

```
<section class="section1" id="videopage">
    <video width=100%, playsinline autoplay muted loop>
        <a href="http://www.naver.com" target="_blank"> 
        <source src="Intro_BLACK.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose the video element in the `a` like so:

```
   <section class="section1" id="videopage">
     <a href="http://www.naver.com" target="_blank" >
        <video width="100%" playsinline autoplay muted loop >
          <source src="Intro_BLACK.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        </video>
     </a>
    </section>
```

Comment: Wow I missed that.. Thanks a lot!